# on multiplicative word identity

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The notation is confusing me so much -

The group $\mathbb{Z}_{\; 5}$ is supposed to have the presentation $\langle x\mid x^{5}=1\rangle$.
That just looks like $\mathbb{Z}_{\; 5} \simeq \{ 0, x, x^{2}, x^{3}, x^{4} \}$

What do I change hahahahahah oh my it is confusing for real because how can I multiply $x$ by $0$ in these 'words' that isn't a multiplicative identity to me at allll

Answer (score 1):

The presentation $\langle x\mid x^{5}=1\rangle$ gives $C_5$, the *abstract* cyclic group of order $5$.

$\mathbb{Z}_5 = \{0,1,2,3,4\}$ with group operation addition mod $5$ is a group isomorphic to $C_5$ via $ 1 \mapsto x$.

$\mathbb{Z}_5$ is a *concrete realization* of $C_5$.